# OneHotEncoded features causing error when input to Classifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I’m trying to prepare data for input to a Decision Tree and Multinomial Naïve Bayes Classifier.

This is what my data looks like (pandas dataframe)

```
Label  Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4

0        1     3       2      1
1        0     1       1      2
2        2     2       1      1
3        3     3       2      3
```

I have split the data into dataLabel and dataFeatures.
Prepared dataLabel using `dataLabel.ravel()`

I need to discretize features so the classifiers treat them as being categorical not numerical.

I’m trying to do this using `OneHotEncoder`

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()

enc.fit(dataFeatures)
chk = enc.transform(dataFeatures)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

mnb = MultinomialNB()

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(mnb, Y, chk, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
```

I get this error - `bad input shape (64, 16)`

This is the shape of label and input

`dataLabel.shape = 72`
`chk.shape = 72,16`

Why won't the classifier accept the onehotencoded features?

**EDIT - Entire Stack trace code**

```
/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils /validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn /cross_validation.py", line 1433, in cross_val_score
for train, test in cv)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
self.results = batch()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1531, in _fit_and_score
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 527, in fit
X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
 File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 515, in check_X_y
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 551, in column_or_1d
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
```

ValueError: bad input shape (64, 16)

Comment: Please show the entire stack trace-- add it to the question.

Comment: I recall being very vexed by how `sklearn` required features to be encoded as input to a `fit` method. I ultimately used Panda's `pd.get_dummies(df)` (as opposed to the `OneHotEncoder` that `sklearn` provided) and that worked when I attempted to fit a random forest.

Comment: @RussellRichie I remember reading somewhere that using `pd.get_dummies` is not recommended because test data will be mapped differently

Comment: @gbhrea, yes, I did have to do some futzing to map test data to same encoding. I'll give the accepted answer a go and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to swap `chk` and `Y` consider [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) documentation. Next, you didn't specify what is `Y` so I hope it's a 1d-array. And the last instead of using separately it's better to combine all transformers within one classifier using [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). Like that:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

clf = Pipeline([
    ('transformer', OneHotEncoder()),
    ('estimator', MultinomialNB()),
])

scores = cross_val_score(clf, dataFeatures.values, Y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
```

Comment: Wow my whole problem was that chk and Y were the wrong way around.. I've been stuck on this for days! Thank you